# Condition append depending on image class, how do I code?

Tags: jquery, image, class

I have two conditions here that reset the images in a table on a change function, but I want those images with a class of browbandtable to be re-set with a different image to browbandtable1.

This is the table, I have two pages one that has browbandtable on it and this one that has browbandtable1.  How would I code it so that it will only use the code if the class matches?

Any help would be appreciated thx

```
 <div id="black1">
    <table width="400" height="100" align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">

      <tr>
    <th align="center" id="img1" scope="col"><img class="browbandtable1"src="images/none1.png" width='18' height='18'></th>
      <th align="center" id="img2" scope="col"><img class="browbandtable1"src="images/none1.png" width='18' height='18'></th>
      <th align="center" id="img3" scope="col" ><img class="browbandtable1"src="images/none1.png"width='18' height='18'></th>
      <th align="center" id="img4" scope="col" ><img class="browbandtable1"src="images/none1.png"width='18' height='18'></th>
      <th align="center" id="img5" scope="col"><img class="browbandtable1"src="images/none1.png" width='18' height='18'></th>
      <th align="center" id="img6"scope="col"><img class="browbandtable1"src="images/none1.png"  width='18' height='18'></th>
      <th align="center" id="img7"scope="col" ><img class="browbandtable1"src="images/none1.png" width='18' height='18'></th>
      <th align="center" id="img8"scope="col"><img class="browbandtable1"src="images/none1.png" width='18' height='18'></th>
      <th align="center" id="img9"scope="col"><img class="browbandtable1"src="images/none1.png" width='18' height='18'></th>
      <th align="center" id="img10"scope="col"><img class="browbandtable1"src="images/none1.png" width='18' height='18'></th>
      <th align="center" id="img11"scope="col"><img class="browbandtable1"src="images/none1.png" width='18' height='18'></th> 
      <th align="center" id="img12"scope="col"><img class="browbandtable1"src="images/none1.png" width='18' height='18'></th>
      <th align="center" id="img13"scope="col"><img class="browbandtable1"src="images/none1.png" width='18' height='18'></th>
      <th align="center" id="img14"scope="col"><img class="browbandtable1"src="images/none1.png" width='18' height='18'></th>
      <th align="center" id="img15"scope="col"><img class="browbandtable1"src="images/none1.png" width='18' height='18'></th>
               <th align="center" id="img16"scope="col"><img class="browbandtable1"src="images/none1.png" width='18' height='18'></th>
      <th align="center" id="img17"scope="col"><img class="browbandtable1"src="images/none1.png" width='18' height='18'></th>
      <th align="center" id="img18"scope="col"><img class="browbandtable1"src="images/none1.png" width='18' height='18'></th>        </tr>
</table></div>
```

//JQUERY CODE

```
$("[id^='img']").append('<img class="browbandtable" src="images/none.png" width="40" height="39">'); 
$("[id^='img']").append('<img class="browbandtable1" src="images/none1.png" width="18" height="18">');
```

Comment: Your question is very confusing. Can you clear it up a bit? Maybe just explain what you're trying to do from scratch. The whole approach seems weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use the `.hasClass()` method.

```
if($("[id^='img']").hasClass("browbandtable1")){
    //Your Code here
}
```

Edit:
I may have misunderstood at first, what you probably want to do is pick your elements in your selector, so

```
$("[id^='img'].browbandtable").append('<img class="browbandtable" src="images/none.png" width="40" height="39">'); 
$("[id^='img.browbandtable1']").append('<img class="browbandtable1" src="images/none1.png" width="18" height="18">');
```

This will select only the elements which have an id starting with image, AND that have the particular class name.

Comment: I fixed it thank you, I needed hasclass as there were two actions to perform, first empty then append. Silly me was emptying the image first, thus removing the class so nothing for the jquery to find...

Comment: @DeniseField Not going to claim I haven't done that before :P Glad I was able to help!